# DT table will not show in Rmarkdown with Word output

Tags: datatables, r-markdown, knitr, dt

I am trying to render a static `DT` to word.

I have this stripped down version of a file `example.Rmd` and I am using `knitr` version 1.30 and the latest stable versions of all relevant packages. Per https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html the `datatable` should render but I am not getting the static `DT` back just the `echo=TRUE` part.

Please help me if you can - I am hopelessly stuck and I cannot just use another table.

---

````
title: 'Main title'
subtitle: 'Subtitle here'
always_allow_html: yes
# params:these will come from SHINY APP
#   x1: x1
#   x2: x2
#   x3 :x3
output:
   word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width = '100%', dpi=300)

```

```{r, fig.align='center', echo=TRUE, cache=FALSE, warning = TRUE, message = TRUE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
if(is.null(webshot:::find_phantom())){webshot::install_phantomjs()}

DT::renderDataTable(iris)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to replace `renderDataTable` with `datatable` which allows `webshot` to kick in.

````
title: 'Main title'
subtitle: 'Subtitle here'
always_allow_html: yes
# params:these will come from SHINY APP
#   x1: x1
#   x2: x2
#   x3 :x3
output:
   word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width = '100%', dpi=300)

```

```{r, fig.align='center', echo=TRUE, cache=FALSE, warning = TRUE, message = TRUE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
if(is.null(webshot:::find_phantom())){webshot::install_phantomjs()}

 DT::datatable(iris)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, I am not sure if you can render DT into a static table file straight into Word like you are wanting, but maybe I am unaware. The DT is a javascript library so it's suppose to be dynamic and user interactive in a web browser. but the `knitr::kable()` function will render your table entirely straight into word.

````
---
title: 'Main title'
subtitle: 'Subtitle here'
always_allow_html: yes
runtime: shiny
output:
    html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width = '100%', dpi=300)

```

```{r, fig.align='center', cache=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
if(is.null(webshot:::find_phantom())){webshot::install_phantomjs()}

DT::renderDataTable(iris)
```
````

[image]

Maybe use just a simple table output with `knitr::kable`, which will render your entire table straight to a word doc from Rmarkdown.

````
---
title: 'Main title'
subtitle: 'Subtitle here'
output:
    word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width = '100%', dpi=300)

```

```{r, fig.align='center', cache=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(DT)
library(knitr)

knitr::kable(iris)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Daniel . Unfortunately I cannot move away from `datatable` as I need to show HTML content heavily modified in a preceding `shiny` app.